# Doing a ranged lookup with multiple variables in a matrix in R

Tags: r, lookup

I feel like I have a bit of a complicated problem (or at least for me it is!).

I have a table of prices which will need to be read from a csv which will look exactly like this:

```
V1 <- c("","Destination","Spain","Spain","Spain","Portugal","Portugal","Portugal","Italy","Italy","Italy")
V2 <- c("","Min_Duration",rep(c(1,3,6),3))
V3 <- c("","Max_Duration",rep(c(2,5,10),3))
V4 <- c("Full-board","Level_1",runif(9,100,200))
V5 <- c("Full-board","Level_2",runif(9,201,500))
V6 <- c("Full-board","Level_3",runif(9,501,1000))
V7 <- c("Half-board","Level_1",runif(9,100,200))
V8 <- c("Half-board","Level_2",runif(9,201,500))
V9 <- c("Half-board","Level_3",runif(9,501,1000))
Lookup_matrix <- as.data.frame(cbind(V1,V2,V3,V4,V5,V6,V7,V8))
```

The prices in the above table will of course come out a bit strange as they're completely random - but we can ignore that...

I also have a table like this:

```
Destination <- c("Spain", "Italy", "Portugal")
Duration <- c(2,4,8)
Level <- c(1,3,3)
Board <- c("Half-board","Half-board","Full-board")
Price <- "Empty"
Price_matrix <- as.data.frame(cbind(Destination,Duration,Level,Board,Price))
```

My question is - how do I populate the 'Price' column of the price matrix with the corresponding prices that can be found in the lookup matrix? Please note that the duration variable of the price matrix will have to fit into a range found between the 'Min_Duration' and 'Max_Duration' columns in the lookup matrix.

In Excel I would use an Index,Match formula. But I'm stumped with R.

Thanks in advance,
Dan

Answer (score 1):

Here is a `tidyverse` possibility

First, please note that I rename your input objects; both `Price_matrix` and `Lookup_matrix` are `data.frame`s (not matrices).

```
df1 <- Price_matrix
df2 <- Lookup_matrix
```

Next we need to fix the column names of `df2 = Lookup_matrix`.

```
# Fix column names
colnames(df2) <- gsub("^_", "", apply(df2[1:2, ], 2, paste0, collapse = "_"))
df2 <- df2[-(1:2), ]
```

We now basically do a left join of `df1` and `df2`; in order for `df2` to be in a suitable format we spread data from wide to long, extract `Price` values for every `Board` and `Level`, and expand entries from `Min_Duration` to `Max_Duration`. Then we join by `Destination`, `Duration`, `Level` and `Board`.

**Note that in your example, `Destination = Italy` has no `Level = 3` entry in `Lookup_matrix`; we therefore get `Price = NA` for this entry.**

```
library(tidyverse)
left_join(
    df1 %>%
        mutate_if(is.factor, as.character) %>%
        select(-Price),
    df2 %>%
        mutate_if(is.factor, as.character) %>%
        gather(key, Price, -Destination, -Min_Duration, -Max_Duration) %>%
        separate(key, into = c("Board", "Level"), sep = "_", extra = "merge") %>%
        mutate(Level = sub("Level_", "", Level)) %>%
        rowwise() %>%
        mutate(Duration = list(seq(as.numeric(Min_Duration), as.numeric(Max_Duration)))) %>%
        unnest() %>%
        select(-Min_Duration, -Max_Duration) %>%
        mutate(Duration = as.character(Duration)))
#Joining, by = c("Destination", "Duration", "Level", "Board")
#  Destination Duration Level      Board            Price
#1       Spain        2     1 Half-board 119.010942545719
#2       Italy        4     3 Half-board             <NA>
#3    Portugal        8     3 Full-board 764.536124917446
```

Answer (score 0):

Using datatable:

```
library(data.table)

nms = trimws(do.call(paste, transpose(Lookup_matrix[1:2, ])))# column names

cat(do.call(paste, c(collapse="\n", Lookup_matrix[-(1:2), ])), file = "mm.csv") 
  # Rewrite the data in the correct format. You do not have to.
  # Just doing Lookup_matrix1 = setNames(Lookup_matrix[-(1:2),],nms) is enough 
  # but it will not have rectified the column classes. 

Lookup_matrix1 = fread("mm.csv", col.names = nms)  

melt(Lookup_matrix1, 1:3)[,
        c("Board", "Level") := .(sub("[.]", "-", sub("\\.Leve.*", "", variable)), sub("\\D+", "", variable))][
        Price_matrix[, -5], on=c("Destination", "Board", "Level", "Min_Duration <= Duration", "Max_Duration >= Duration")]

  Destination Min_Duration Max_Duration           variable    value      Board Level
1:       Spain            2            2 Half.board.Level_1 105.2304 Half-board     1
2:       Italy            4            4               <NA>       NA Half-board     3
3:    Portugal            8            8 Full.board.Level_3 536.5132 Full-board     3
```